# Error with Youtube Java API while setting user credentials

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, uri

Im trying to connect on my youtube account through my java desktop application using the youtube java api, i've followed this guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java?hl=pt-BR#ClientLogin_for_Installed_Applications looks easy, but im getting an error, here´s my code:

```
    String developer_key = "key123456789"; // Registered developer key
    String application_name = "app"; // Registered application name
    String user_account = "user@gmail.com"; // Server's Youtube account
    String user_password = "mypass"; // Server's Youtube password

    YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(application_name, developer_key);

    try {
        service.setUserCredentials(user_account, user_password);
    } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException: Error connecting with login URI
```

The error is happening at setUserCredentials function, someone knows what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, i'm under a proxy, (I already had changed system properties to connect with this proxy), but youtube use https for user login intead of http, so in the proxy setting I just added a https proxy and now works, here´s my code:

```
        if(Assets.HTTP_USE_PROXY) {
        System.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
        System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", Assets.HTTP_PROXY_HOST);
        System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", Integer.toString(Assets.HTTP_PROXY_PORT));
        if(Assets.HTTP_REQUIRE_AUTH) {
            System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", Assets.HTTP_PROXY_USER);
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", Assets.HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD);
            Authenticator.setDefault(
                      new Authenticator() {
                        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                          return new PasswordAuthentication(Assets.HTTP_PROXY_USER, 
                                  Assets.HTTP_PROXY_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
                        }
                      }
                    );
        }
    }
```